# React Async Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am struggling with **Async Select** from `react-select`. I managed to display some defaultOptions and do an async fetch of its options using promises and `loadOptions` prop.

What I need is to have the options updated (resolve the promise) when the dropdown of options is displayed on click. Is there a way to execute the same promise `onClick` (even in `onChange`)?

I am using the following codepen provided by `react-select` team https://codesandbox.io/s/7w4w9yyrmx?module=/example.js

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually found a way to solve it using a basic `react-select`. I am going to manage the `options` using a react state being set `onMenuOpen`. Using this approach, I have control on what options are displayed when the user clicks on the select.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vnmvrwoj63

Answer (score 1):

By enabling `defaultOptions` as `true` the Component will immediately load the `loadOptions`. So it is working as intended.

There is actually no way to update the `options` because it will only do that if there is a `inputValue && loadedInputValue`. You could provide a Pull Request to add that feature.

```
 render() {
      const { loadOptions, ...props } = this.props;
      const {
        defaultOptions,
        inputValue,
        isLoading,
        loadedInputValue,
        loadedOptions,
        passEmptyOptions,
      } = this.state;
      const options = passEmptyOptions
        ? []
        : inputValue && loadedInputValue ? loadedOptions : defaultOptions || [];
      return (
        // $FlowFixMe
        <SelectComponent
          {...props}
          filterOption={this.props.filterOption || null}
          ref={ref => {
            this.select = ref;
          }}
          options={options}
          isLoading={isLoading}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      );
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Async.js#L150-L176